# How do I create my own Github badge?

Tags: github, webhooks, badge

I would like to create a badge for my Github repo which shows as failing or passing based on a set script that I run as a webhook on each commit.

This would be a custom script and would be run every commit, how would I be able to create this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you need a script which ill return an image with current build status. Then you can include it as an image into a README.md of your repository.

The webhook has nothing to do with the image but will have to trigger your custom script which verifies new build.

Comment: can you share an example?